# Grid Items to fill the screen ... xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

how can I set the size of the grid Items in a GridView control so that the Items will auto 
re-size to fill the screen . for example if there was 2 items each will fill half of the screen and if there was 3 each will take the third and so on .. thanks

Comment: do you try to ask Mr. Google and Mr. MSDN first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ItemStyle.Width` property on the column definition.

If you are not using `autogenerated` columns, to set the width of the columns you are interested in.

If you are using dynamically generated columns, the you will need to set the width in your code behind.

**Refer Following:**

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "";
    try
    {
      int colWidth = Int16.Parse(Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text));
      if (colWidth > 0)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
          GridView1.Columns[i].ItemStyle.Width = colWidth;
        }
      }
    }
    catch
    {
      Label1.Text = "An error occurred."
    }
}
```

**Check This MSDN:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178296.aspx

**Referance Link:**

http://forums.asp.net/t/1176980.aspx

Comment: thanks for the help . but is there a way to do it in Xaml for a windows store app .. I don't seen to find the autogenrated in order to set it to false ..